# Where is the .minecraft folder on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I have windows 10 and have already tried holding the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button and <kbd>R</kbd> at the same time.

I typed `%appdata%` and couldn't find it, so then I typed `%appdata%\.minecraft` but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to go into Windows Explorer
(this program: [image: Windows Explorer window]
And type in that big top box:

```
%appdata%
```

You should find the minecraft folder in there.